# Select file instead of just folder in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This code:

The user just selects a folder but the file name should always be named the same in order to work. How can I make it to ask for a file?

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select main folder: ")
#folder = path.Path(fname)
x = pd.read_csv(folder + '\\20180911_Dataset_b.csv', sep = ',', encoding = "utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For asking a file instead of folder, use:

```
filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on its parameters and how they work and I will accept your answer :D

Comment: @user10522417 You can find help here:  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm